# "Adidas (brand) Superstar Boost (shoe name) Shoes" or "Adidas Superstar Boost shoes"?

Tags: capitalization

Whenever I want to write the name of a brand's product, do I also have to capitalize what the item is, like shirt or hat?

1. Did you buy the new Supreme Polartec Pullover Shirt?
2. Did you buy the new Supreme Polartec pullover shirt?

Another example would be:

1. In what sizes are the Adidas Superstar Boost Shoes?
2. In what sizes are the Adidas Superstar Boost shoes?

Comment: What would make you think that, Bob. D'you know anyone who drives a Ford Car? Drinks Champagne Sparkling Wine? Eats toasted Bread?

Not only do you not need to; you need not to.

Comment: Sometimes the full name of the product includes the common words that describe the category. In that case you probably should capitalize the whole phrase.

Answer (score 1):

If the word for the product is not a proper name, it would not be capitalized:  Borden milk, Mahatma rice, Kraft cheese, Wendy's hamburgers.  It being modified by a proper name doesn't matter.

If it is a proper name or part of a proper name, it would be capitalized:  Tiger's Milk, Kellogg's Frosted Flakes, Angie's List.